# Checkbox in data grid change in second click

Tags: silverlight

I have datagrid in my silverlight project and one of his cloumn contain a checkbox element.

When i click on the checkbox to remove the selection or select it, nothing work. 
But when i click in the second time it works well.

My conclusion till now is that the firsr click insert the checkbox into edit mode and the then the second click actualy change the value.

There is a way to change this behavior?

Thanx a lot !

Comment: FYI Often the problem is that actually the first click is selecting that row/item. Until that row is selected the controls won't respond to interactions. In the worst cases I've seen it take 3 clicks to activate a control: first to select the row, second to put it into edit mode and the 3rd to actually use the control.

Comment: Put `ClickMode="Press"` on your checkbox and don't use a CellEditingTemplate for it just a CellTemplate